# Que se necesita para usar pyautogui en python?

Tags: python

Recientemente he tratado de aprender el lenguaje Python y me he topado con un "Bache" por así decirlo trate de realizar un ejercicio simple tratando de buscar una imagen en concreto con la librería pyautogui pero me encotre con este error :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bueno tengo instalado OPENCV ya que me dijeron se necesitaba y aparte no encuentro errores de sintaxis que afecten, no tengo idea de  cual puede ser el problema acá, paso el codigo que estoy usando y me ayudaria mucho si alguin sabe que esta pasando aca:

```
PIC_J = "IMG\Captura.PNG"

object_j = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("IMG\Captura.PNG")


if object_j:
    # imprimo si no encuentra el objeto
    print('OBJETO ENCONTRADO')
else:
        print('xxxxx OBJETO NO ENCONTRADO xxxx')
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Te invito a hacer el [tour]. Es importante que dejes los mensajes de error como texto, no como imagen, por lo que sería bueno [edit] tu pregunta y dejarlo de esa forma.  Finalmente, el error indica que no está instalado un paquete que es necesario, en este caso, [Pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/)

Comment: Hola Harold, buscando encontré [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71213028/pyautogui-error-the-pillow-package-is-required-to-use-this-function)... tal vez te sirva (está en ingles).

Comment: Marce Muchas gracias pues si basicamente debia de actualizar la libreria Muchas gracias